# Custom menu for registered customers error

Tags: php, authentication

I am getting an error when i try to show a diff set of menu if a customer is logged in,
when someone log in the footer just jump from bottom to top. when i remove this custom menu, website is fine. can some one please help.

Thank you.

the code im using for the menu switch is

```
            <div class="login">

<?php if ($regid=='') { ?>
        <a href="registration" class="login_style"> Register </a> |
        <a href="login" class="login_style"> Login </a></div>
<?php }?>       

<?php if ($regid!='') { ?>

        <div class="login"> 

                    <a href="my_order" class="login_style"> My Orders </a> |
                    <a href="view_profile" class="login_style"> View Profile </a> |
                    <a href="edit_profile" class="login_style"> Edit Profile </a> |
                    <a href="changepass" class="login_style"> Change Password </a> |
                    <a href="signout" class="login_style"> Signout </a> 




        </div>
<?php }?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agree with above. The tag is unclosed which would cause an error. Try:

```
<div class="login">
<?php if ($regid=='') { ?>
        <a href="registration" class="login_style"> Register </a> |
        <a href="login" class="login_style"> Login </a></div>
    <?php } else if ($regid!='') { ?>
        <a href="my_order" class="login_style"> My Orders </a> |
        <a href="view_profile" class="login_style"> View Profile </a> |
        <a href="edit_profile" class="login_style"> Edit Profile </a> |
        <a href="changepass" class="login_style"> Change Password </a> |
        <a href="signout" class="login_style"> Signout </a> 
    <?php }?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have:

`<div class="login">`

twice. It could be that an unclosed tag is causing the issue.